# Google react chart custom event handling

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-visualization

I had added a event on react-google chart (barchart) if user click on bar then it will show data and details related to that bar but the problem is sometimes it select row and sometimes it select column.
And second problem if I click other part of graph it will trigger the event that is good but if I click bar first and then other part of the graph it is triggering the event handler which I don't want.

```
  <Chart chartType="Bar" width={'100%'} height={'100%'} data = {this.props.data.data.chartData}
                                            options = {{

                                            }}
                                           chartEvents ={[
                                                    {
                                                      eventName: "select",
                                                      callback: ({ chartWrapper, google}) =>{
                                                        console.log(chartWrapper)
                                                        const chart = chartWrapper.getChart();
                                                        const selected = chart.getSelection();
                                                        // const dataTable = chartWrapper.getDataTable();
                                                        const [selectedItem] = selected;
                                                        const { row, column } = selectedItem
                                                        if(row){
                                                          this.barClicked()
                                                        }
                                                        // console.log(dataTable.getValue(row, column))
                                                      }
                                            }
                                        ]}
                                    />
```

Comment: the default behavior of the select event is to select the bar when it is clicked. if the bar is clicked again, and already selected, it will be un-selected. the event will fire on both instances. when first selected, `getSelection` will return an array of the selected rows (and columns, if more than one series exists). when un-selected, `getSelection` will return an empty array. if a legend entry is clicked / selected, `getSelection` will only return the column. it should not fire when clicking any other part of the chart.

Comment: see [the-select-event](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/events#the-select-event) for more info...